# Index and XMatch in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, index-match

I want to get the data from Pivot table using 3 references. I already did it using 2 references but when adding another reference, it's showing an error. Can you help me?

Please see the formula used below:

```
=INDEX(Pivot!$B$5:$G$154,XMATCH(Final!E120,Pivot!$B$5:$B$154,0),XMATCH(Final!C120,Pivot!$B$5:$B$154,0))
```

I already tried adding another XMATCH, but it seems like it won't match, or XMATCH can only look up to 2 references.

I also used index match but same issue. I am actually using rows and columns as reference.

I am expecting to return the value from my Pivot table.
[image: Sample]

Comment: My suspicion is that you may be misunderstanding what the INDEX function is actually doing.  You give at a column and a row reference and it returns the value at that location.  For instance, if your first XMATCH finds the value in the 6th row of the table, and the second XMATCH finds the value in the 8th column of the table, then the INDEX will return the value located row 6, column 8 in the target table.  There is no place for a 3rd reference.  This will require a different approach, which will require a more complete explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: BTW, the “best practice” way to retrieve data from a pivot table is a not-often-discussed function `GETPIVOTDATA`.  I would read up on how it works at something like https://exceljet.net/functions/getpivotdata-function and see if that isn’t  better direction for you.